# Less animated scene transitions in Cocos2d 3 in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, scene

I am now working with Cocos2d 3 RC1 for iOS and I can't find all the transitions I had with previews versions of Cocos2d. In the documentation I can only find the following transitions:

- transitionCrossFadeWithDuration:
- transitionFadeWithColor:duration:
- transitionFadeWithDuration:
- transitionMoveInWithDirection:duration:
- transitionPushWithDirection:duration:
- transitionRevealWithDirection:duration:

Where are the other ones? for example the FlipXRightOver, FlipYUpOver, etc. Do those transitions still exist? How could I use them in Cocos2d 3?

The release notes of Cocos2d 3 only says "New shader based scene transitions" but doesn't say anything about the old transitions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check the changelog and roadmap/git issues, if they aren't available in code they're gone (for now). You should ask this on the cocos forum.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely post this in the cocos forum. I also went to check the CCTransition.h/m files and the transitions I was looking for were not there. Not sure if they will support these transitions.